# When I run, I cannot walk

Tags: riddle

> I can run, but I cannot walk.
>
> When not running, I cannot move.
>
> I only move back and forth.
>
> When I move, I move not only me.
>
> People cannot talk to me without sounding strange.
>
> I am not wet. If I get wet, I may kill you.
>
> I usually run only when it is hot.

Who or what am I?

Comment: I'm not a fan of spoiler-tagged hints ruling out otherwise fitting solutions (as per your comments on them), since some people choose not to look at hints. I'd suggest unspoilering them, or finding a way to add their content to the riddle.

Comment: I unhid the spoilers and added them to the riddle, as per your suggestion.  The reason I added the lines is to make the riddle less vague by giving more criteria for the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> an electric fan

Why?

> A fan moves back and forth (well, moving fans do). Fan moves air. If you get a fan wet, the electronic components could possibly kill you. If you talk into a fan, you sound strange. People generally run fans when they are hot.

Comment: Well done again, Josh. +1

Answer (score 2):

> Water

It runs, but doesn't walk.

If it's moving, it's running.

It moves other things along with it. Just ask Huck Finn or [Pikachu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/7820/1563).

And it definitely makes voices sound strange, if by talking *to* it you mean talking *in* it.

Comment: Very clever, but it is definitely talk to me, not in me.

Comment: I didn't mean to say you wrote the wrong word, just that if you talk "to" it close enough, you end up "in" it.

Comment: I added more hints, so that the riddle is not too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> A river

I can run, but I cannot walk.

> A river runs but does not walk

When not running, I cannot move.

> When a river does not run, it stays still and does not move

When I move, I move not only me.

> A river carries many things when it flows

People cannot talk to me without
sounding strange.

> Listening to the words spoken by a person when we are underwater will surely sound strange!

Comment: I added more hints so that the riddle is not too broad.